# NSOpenGLView toggle to fullscreen from within the view

Tags: cocoa, fullscreen, nsopenglview

I'm trying to create a method that will toggle between fullscreen and a window. I'm trying to do this from within a class inherited from NSOpenGLView, <strike>essentially following [this blogpost](http://stevechallis.com/2010/feb/06/taking-opengl-fullscreen-with-cocoa/)</strike>. That works once, going from windowed to fullscreen; trying to go back fails in various ways: the window screen doesn't get updated, or I don't even manage switch to the window but the fullscreen just blanks out. Trying to go back and forth a few times anyway (mapped it to the 'f' key), the program often locks up, and in a worst case, I have to restart my computer.
I've attached the code for the method below; for debugging purposes, I've set the full frame rectangle much smaller, so that if things freeze, the application is never at full screen.

The [fullscreen example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/GLFullScreen/Introduction/Intro.html) in the Apple developer examples suggest using a controller, and does not go fullscreen from within the inherited NSOpenGLView.

My questions:

- should I use a controller instead, and from there switch between windowed and fullscreen (creating a separate fullscreen view each time)? Or should both methods work?
- If both methods should work, which one is preferred?
- If both methods can work, what am I doing wrong in the current way of implementing this?
- or, is there a third, better, method?

Note that for both references, I'll have to assume that things haven't changed for 10.8 (both references seem to apply to 10.6).

Code follows:

```
@implementation MyOpenGLView

[...]

- (void)toggleFullscreen
{
    mainWindow = [self window];

    if (isFullscreen) {
        [fullscreenWindow close];
        [mainWindow setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
        [mainWindow setContentView: self];
        [mainWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront: self];
        [mainWindow makeFirstResponder: self];
        isFullscreen = false;
    } else {
        [mainWindow setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:NO];
        //NSRect fullscreenFrame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
        NSRect fullscreenFrame = { {300, 300}, {300, 300} };
        fullscreenWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:fullscreenFrame
                                                       styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                                         backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                           defer:NO];
        if (fullscreenWindow) {
            [fullscreenWindow setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
            [fullscreenWindow setTitle:@"Full screen"];
            [fullscreenWindow setReleasedWhenClosed: YES];
            [fullscreenWindow setContentView: self];
            [fullscreenWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront: self];
            //[fullscreenWindow setOpaque:YES];
            //[fullscreenWindow setHidesOnDeactivate:YES];
            // Set the window level to be just above the menu bar
            //[fullScreenWindow setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel+1];
            // Set the window level to be just below the screen saver
            [fullscreenWindow setLevel:NSScreenSaverWindowLevel-1];
            [fullscreenWindow makeFirstResponder:self];

            isFullscreen = true;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: could not switch to full screen.");
        }
   }
}

[...]

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I now think this can't be done, and should not be done. When windowed, the rendering context is a window, which is a different beast than a screen, when rendering fullscreen.
Thus, when switching between, things have to re-setup everytime you switch.

It is possible to simply use the native fullscreen option that is in the newest OS X variants. This will (presumably) enlarge the containg window to full screen size while removing the frame, borders and buttons. Thus, you're still rendering to a window, though it looks fullscreen.

I'm not sure if this option makes things slower: there's a window layer in between, which could make it a slower than rendering directly to a screen.

For the curious, implementing the native fullscreen is ridiculously easy (at least in 10.8 and 10.9): In XCode, select the `.xib` file, select the (main) window in the editor's sidebar, then select the attributes selector on the right. You can find a "Full Screen" selection between Unsupported, Primary Window or Auxiliary Window. That will automatically add the full screen toggle to the window.
Even neater, now select the main menu -> view menu in the sidebar, find the "Full Screen Menu Item" in the inspector at the bottom (there's a search bar for it), drag it into the View menu in the editor, and voilà, it will have a shortcut and automatically connect to the full screen option for the window (select the new View menu item and look at the Connections inspector to it's already connected for you).

A nice way to test all this is to grab the [full screen example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/GLFullScreen/Introduction/Intro.html) I linked in my question, and edit it as suggested above. Using the default control-command F shortcut to toggle back and forth between fullscreen will show the opengl view *and* the frame with text below it in a full screen. Using the fullscreen option as coded in the example will toggle the openglview to use the fullscreen, without any extra (Cocoa) frames, buttons or text.

Comment: I think for your first example, it is just a CGL fullscreen surface.  See the book by Robert P. Kuehne for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about this too- specifically your first two bullet point questions.

This doesn't address those questions, but your third one about the bug, I think you can get away with just changing the properties of the same window (works for me):

```
- (void)toggleFullscreen
{
    if (isFullscreen) {
        NSRect windowFrame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame];
        [mainWindow setStyleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask |
                             NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask ];
        [mainWindow setFrame:windowFrame display:true];
        [mainWindow setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
        [mainWindow setLevel:NSNormalWindowLevel];
        [mainWindow setTitle:@"SimpleOculus"];
        [mainWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
        [mainWindow makeFirstResponder:self];
        isFullscreen = false;
    }
    else {
        NSRect fullscreenFrame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
        [mainWindow setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
        [mainWindow setFrame:fullscreenFrame display:true];
        [mainWindow setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
        [mainWindow setLevel:NSScreenSaverWindowLevel-1];
        [mainWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
        [mainWindow makeFirstResponder:self];
        isFullscreen = true;
    }
}
```